# .NET Core DI resolving keyed services using custom delegate returns null

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, .net-core-2.2

I am struggling with a weird case. I have a .NET Core console application that is setup like this:

```cs
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var runAsService = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("console"));
    var builder = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => { loggingBuilder.AddConsole(); });

            services.AddGatewayServers();
            services.AddHostedService<GatewayService>();
        });

    if (runAsService)
        await builder.RunServiceAsync();
    else
        await builder.RunConsoleAsync();
}
```

I then have extensions on `IServiceCollection` that sets up `AddGatewayServers()` like this:

```cs
public static void AddGatewayServers(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IGatewayServer, Server1>();
    services.AddTransient<IGatewayServer, Server2>();
    services.AddTransient<Func<ServerType, IGatewayServer>>(provider => key =>
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case ServerType.Type1: return provider.GetService<Server1>();
            case ServerType.Type2: return provider.GetService<Server2>();
            default: return null;
        }
    });
}
```

And then in my class I inject the dependency like this:

```cs
private readonly Func<ServerType, IGatewayServer> _gatewayAccessor;

public GatewayServerCollection(Func<ServerType, IGatewayServer> gatewayAccessor)
{
    _gatewayAccessor = gatewayAccessor;
}
```

But when I call the `_gatewayAccessor` later on in `GatewayServerCollection` to get me an instance of the `IGatewayServer` it returns `null`. I call it like:

```cs
var server = _gatewayAccessor(ServerType.Type1);
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Change the `GetService<T>` calls inside the `AddGatewayServers` method to `GetRequiredService<T>` instead, and try again.

Comment: You don't need to make the function a transient dependency. It doesn't change from one executin to the next

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Steven. Already tried that. I get the exception (as GetRequiredService method is supposed to throw if it cant find the registration)

Comment: @Jinish: Exactly! You registered the types with the `IGatewayServer` service type. T his means you can *only* resolve it by that type. You should register them by their concrete type instead.

Comment: That makes sense @PanagiotisKanavos. Thanks for tjhe observation. However, adding it as scoped or singleton doesnt help me get the resolved instance. All i get is null in all cases

Comment: @Jinish what is  `_gatewayServers` and where does it come from? How is it initialized? Your constructor assigns `gatewayAccessor` to `_gatewayAccessor`. It looks like the wrong `Func<>` is called. f all those are typos please fix the question's code.

Comment: Although @PanagiotisKanavos is correct, the `provider` input `parameter` argument is only reused within a single scope. Different scopes get a different `parameter` value. So be careful not to register your delegate as `Singleton`, as this would cause captive dependencies when one of `Server1` or `Server2`'s dependencies are `Scoped` or short(er) lived.

Comment: @Jinish add a breakepoint in the constructor *and* the line where you try to access the func, step into it and see what function is actually called. I suspect it's not the one you registered

Comment: Thanks for noticing this @Steven. That was it. I completely disregarded this that I was registering the types as IGatewayServer. Registering them as concrete types solved the issue (and makes perfect sense). Thanks. If you added that as an answer I will be most happy to mark it so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your registration to the following:

```
public static void AddGatewayServers(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<Server1>();
    services.AddTransient<Server2>();
    services.AddScoped<Func<ServerType, IGatewayServer>>(provider => (key) =>
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case ServerType.Type1: return provider.GetRequiredService<Server1>();
            case ServerType.Type2: return provider.GetRequiredService<Server2>();
            default: throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException(
                typeof(ServerType), (int)key, nameof(key));
        }
    });
}
```

The most important change is from this:

```
services.AddTransient<IGatewayServer, Server1>();
services.AddTransient<IGatewayServer, Server2>();
```

To this:

```
services.AddTransient<Server1>();
services.AddTransient<Server2>();
```

The registrations in MS.DI from a simple dictionary mapping from a service type (`IGatewayServer`) to an implementation (`Server1` or `Server2` respectively). When you request `Server1`, it can't find `typeof(Server1)` in its dictionary. The solution, therefore, is to register those types by their concrete type.

On top of that, I made use of the `GetRequiredService` method:

```
provider.GetRequiredService<Server1>()
```

Instead of `GetService`:

```
provider.GetService<Server1>()
```

`GetRequiredService` will throw an exception when a registration does not exist, which allows your code to fail-fast.

I changed the registration of the delegate from `Transient`:

```
services.AddTransient<Func<ServerType, IGatewayServer>>
```

to `Scoped`:

```
services.AddScoped<Func<ServerType, IGatewayServer>>
```

This prevents it from being injected into any `Singleton` consumer, as MS.DI only prevents `Scoped` services to be injected into `Singleton` consumers, but does not prevent `Transient` instances from being injected into `Scoped` or `Singleton` consumers (but do make sure [validation is enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectioncontainerbuilderextensions.buildserviceprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions_BuildServiceProvider_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Boolean_)). In case you register it as `Transient`, the delegate would be injected into `Singleton` consumers, but this would eventually fail at runtime when you call `GetRequiredService` when the requested service depends on a `Scoped` lifestyle, as that would cause [Captive Dependencies](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/). Or it could even cause memory leaks, when you resolve `Transient` components that implement `IDisposable` (yuck!). Registering the delegate as `Singleton`, however, would also cause the same issues with Captive Dependencies. So `Scoped` is the only sensible option.

Instead of returning `null` for an unknown `ServerType`:

```
default:
    return null;
```

I throw an exception, allowing the application to fail fast:

```
default:
    throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException(...);
```