# Resolve DI of a Service based on condition

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a store with 2 kinds of store as follows

```
interface IStore {}
class AStore : IStore {}
class BStore : IStore {}
```

Then I have a Service

```
public Service : IService 
{
    public Service(IStore store) {}
}
```

It means we can pass AStore or BStore based on the condition of enum Store

```
enum Store { A, B }

if Store.A => return AStore
if Store.B => return BStore
```

**In a controller, I have an action to pass the Store as a parameter and get an instance of Service to proceed something**

For example

```
public Task Get(Store store)
{
    // How I can get Service instance with Store parameter which depends on IStore?
}
```

The question is how I can take advantage of DI in ASP.Net Core to solve Service which depends on IStore?

Comment: One approach is to use keyed services with a custom delegate.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55494896/net-core-di-resolving-keyed-services-using-custom-delegate-returns-null

Answer (score 0):

ok so you can implement something like this

```
interface IStore<T> where T : StoreFactoryBase
{
 string DoSomething();
}
```

then

```
  class Store<T> : IStore<T> where T : StoreFactoryBase{
  private readonly StoreFactoryBase instance = null;
  Store()
  {
   instance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
  }

  public string DoSomething()
  {
    instance.DoSomething()
  }
```

}

now you need to create different services which ineherit  StoreFactoryBase

ie

```
public class A:StoreFactoryBase
{
Public virtual string DoSomething()
{
return "Hello from Class A";
}
}





 public class B:StoreFactoryBase
 {
  Public virtual string  DoSomething()
   {
    return "Hello from Class B";
   }
  }
```

now you can implement your base class as either abstract class like this

```
  public abstract class StoreFactoryBase
    {
      public abstract string DoSomething();
    }
```

now here is the DI Part when you inject your service in startup class it will look something like this

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IStore<>), typeof(Store<>));
```

now when you inject your service to controller say like this

```
private readonly IStore<A>storeA;
private readonly IStore<B>storeB;
SomeController(IStore<A>storeeA,IStore<B>storeB)
{
this.StoreA =storeeA;
this.storeB =storeB;
}
```

the A will execute As Method whereas B will execute Bs Method

**UPDATE**

say on condition you want to switch the method/store

then

```
if(storeA)
{
storeA.DoSOmething();
}
else StoreB.DoSOmething();
```